# Sending Emails to users using Spring boot starter mail and Schedule cron

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, cron-task, spring-scheduled

**I created a simple Spring boot application which sends the emails using smtp and schedule cron job.**

Below is the my code:

**This is main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class ServicewithEmailApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServicewithEmailApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is the service class which gets the list of actions and then send email to them:**

```
@Service
public class Employeeservice {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Employeeservice.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduling.job.cron}")
    public void sendreminders() {

        Date date = new Date();
        //get the list of actions from db which due date is greater than current date
        List<ActionItems> Items = emprepo.findByDuedateAfter(date);

        for (ActionItems action : Items) {
            sendMail(action);
        }

    }

    // method to send reminders to users
    public void sendMail(ActionItems action) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(action.getEmail());
        message.setSubject("Pending Tasks");
        message.setText(action.getName() + " your action: " + '"' + action.getAction() + '"'
                + "  is pending due date is:" + action.getDuedate());
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

**This is the Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<ActionItems, Integer>
{
    List<ActionItems> findByDuedateAfter(@Param("date") java.util.Date date);      //using method
}
```

**This is the Model ActionItems class**

```
@Entity
public class ActionItems {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String action;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Date duedate;
   
    //getters   and  //setters
}
```

**Note: Database related & mail related properties are in application.properties file**

The above code is working fine able to send mails daily

**Questions:**

1. Is there any better solution other than Cron schedule?
2. is there any Optimization for sending emails?(there could be hundreds of Acion Items, as in the above
   code i used for loop to iterete each action item and then calling send email method?

**Thanks in advance!..**

Comment: You can use CompletableFuture/@Async for your sendMail method.

Comment: Depending on the load but, maybe, it is worth to use a messaging system (i.e. RabbitMQ) to send them and, to process them separately from any other process that generates them.

Comment: @VaibS  i used Async annotation but still i didn't find any differences in time, i just processed 5 emails(without Aync) for which the time taken is: 29471 milliseconds, and with Async time taken:28472 milliseconds

Comment: as per my logs i observed, for each action item it is again trying to login to my sender email Id then sending,  how can i achieve single time login and then send multiple emails

Comment: @CHILUKABHARATH There are higher chances that your method didn't really run in Async mode as private methods don't work in Async (As it only works on proxies). To check, you can add log in your method and see if it was executed simultaneously or not.

Comment: @fjavierm, you mean i need to Iterate through the Items and prepare each mail message then send  that mail message to Rabbitmq queue then i need to add Listener to that Queue then receive that created mail message and trigger that mailsender.send(message).             i didn't understand how will it improve the processing of mails?

Comment: @CHILUKABHARATH The idea is to just send the request of "Send a message" to the queue and, when the message is consumed from the queue, prepare it and send it.
It has some advantages like:
- Your main action, maybe trigger by a user, does not need to process and prepare the message.
- A queue can have multiple consumers, as much as you need, depending on your load
- The message system can be different to the system triggering the email.
- If prepare the message is a very costly operation, it does not affect the performance of your main server and, as said, you can have multiple consumers.